# Adding meta data in ember-cli-mirage route handler

Tags: ember.js, acceptance-testing, json-api, ember-cli-mirage

I need to return meta in my [ember-cli-mirage](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com) route handler data along with the serialised objects in my tests

```
server.createList('things', 42);

this.get('/things', function(schema, request) {
  return this.serialize(this.schema.things.all());
});
```

I'd like the route handler to output:

```
{ data: ..., meta: { 'record-count': 42 } }
```

Is there a way to set up Mirage to do this or do I need to explicitly set that data on every request?

Answer (score 0):

Ember CLI Mirage uses Serializers similar to Ember Data that allows you to do such stuff. Adding meta data is explicitly mentioned for the [`serialize` method](https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/api/modules/lib/serializer~Serializer#serialize) of Ember CLI Mirage's Serializer in documentation:

> You can also override this method, call super, and manipulate the data before Mirage responds with it. This is a great place to add metadata

I've not tested above code but it should give you an idea:

```js
serialize(primaryResource, request) {
  // This is how to call super, as Mirage borrows [Backbone's implementation of extend](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-extend)
  let json = Serializer.prototype.serialize.apply(this, arguments);

  // Add metadata, sort parts of the response, etc.
  json.meta = {
    'record-count': primaryResource.length,
  };

  return json;
}
```